# return keyboard on entering one character in textfield

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uitextfield

I am developing an iphone application in which i have to return keyboard as soon as i type only one character in textfield. How to achieve this please suggest some solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step 1: Create a class implementing the protocol UITextFieldDelegate

```
@interface TheDelegateClass : NSObject <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Step 2: In your implementation, override the method - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    // newString is what the user is trying to input.
    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    if ([newString length] < 1) {
        // If newString is blank we will just ingore it.
        return YES;
    } else
    {
        // Otherwise we cut the length of newString to 1 (if needed) and set it to the textField.
        textField.text = [newString length] > 1 ? [newString substringToIndex:1] : newString;
        // And make the keyboard disappear.
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        // Return NO to not change text again as we've already changed it.
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Step 3: Set an instance of the delegate class as the delegate of the UITextField.

```
TheDelegateClass *theDelegate = [[TheDelegateClass alloc] init];
[theTextField setDelegate:theDelegate];
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to write your code in text delegate method of

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
   if([textField.text length] == 1){
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

and then check your length of string in `textFieldDidBeginEditing`

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    if([textField.text length] == 1){
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for help but i want to return keyboard as soon as i enter only one characters in textfield wihout pressing done button

Comment: then write the code in shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string it check one by one character

Answer (score 0):

add notification in textField creating code

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(changeText:) name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:textField];
```

and implement

```
- (void) changeText: (id) sender;
{
    if ([textField.text length] == 1) 
    {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }        
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help but i want to return keyboard as soon as i enter only one characters in textfield wihout pressing done button

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is want you are looking for?

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField 
{
   [textField resignFirstResponder];
   [add your method here];
    return YES;

}
```

Or if you want it to resign as soon as it starts to edit you can put this code in textFieldDidBeginEditing: delegate method

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
```

check this link

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
   if([textField.text length] == 1){
       [textField resignFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   if([textField.text length]==1)
   {
       // here perform the action you want to do
   }

}
```